# SBT: Java Annotation Processors and compileIncremental error

Tags: java, annotations, sbt

I’m using the immutables.org and mapstruct annotation processors in my sbt project (I've moved them to subprojects, so they don't interfere with each other).

Sometimes, compiling my project fails in compileIncremental because the annotation processor would create a new file, but the compiler already read the previously generated file or I changed my interface in src/main/java but the (previously) generated sources still "implement" the old interface (they would be overwritten, but that happens only after processing the sources in src/main/java).

My workaround was to create a task that deletes the generated sources beforehand for which "(compile in Compile)" would depend on.

Is there another way to do this? like disabling compileIncremental for one single project? or specifying the order of compilation? (like first normal sources, then unmanagedSources)

Alternatively finding out if the sourceFiles really changed and only then deleting the generated sources would also work for me, but I’m not sure how to approach that.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks,
Dominik

Comment: Could you share you build file ?